# VueJS data property returns undefined in mounted function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I've made a get request using Axios which returns some data as expected, but I cannot access the app's data properties in the mounted function to assign the results of the request. The console log to `this.productList` returns `undefined`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
new Vue({
    el: '#products',
    data: function(){
        return{
            test: 'Hello',
            productList: null
        }
    },
    mounted: function(){
        axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json').then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(this.productList)
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
    
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because in that function, `this` doesn't refer to your vue instance. It has another meaning.

You can make a temporary variable to hold the value of `this` in the outer function, like this:

```js
mounted: function() {

  let $vm = this;

  axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log($vm.productList)
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Or you can use the nicer arrow functions:

```js
mounted: function() {

  axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json').then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(this.productList)
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for these answers. Why does the use of the arrow functions change what 'this' references?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch) out

Comment: Your answer  worked in my case as i assigned "this" to a variable
but can you explain how it worked

Comment: @MohammadFahadRao `this` is a reserved variable that depends on the scope it's accessed on. If you try to access `this` in a inner function, it will have a different value than the one in the outer function. By attributing `this` from the parent scope to a variable, you can access it in inner scopes.