# setting variable in asynchronous javascript call

Tags: jquery, asynchronous-javascript

I have an object `x` of class `C`. The attribute `x.myval` should be set by calling `x.load()`, which in turn should get its data from an asynchronous ajax call.

```js
class C {
    constructor() {
        this.myval = "hello";
    }
    load() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "file.txt",
            // suppress "xml not well-formed error in firefox", 
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                if (xhr.overrideMimeType) { xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain"); }
            },
            contentType: "text/plain",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(text) {
                this.myval = text;
            }
        });
    }
}

var x = new C();
$.when(x.load()).done(function(a1,a2) {
    console.log(x.text); //should print the content of file.txt
});
```

I get an error `this.myval is undefined`, obviously because `this` is set to `this` of jquery-`$`.

I also tried:

```js
class C {
    constructor() {
        this.myval = "hello";
    }
    load() {
        var callback = function callbackClosure(mythis) {return function(text) {
            this.myval = text;
        }}(this);

        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "file.txt",
            // suppress "xml not well-formed error in firefox", 
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                if (xhr.overrideMimeType) { xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain"); }
            },
            contentType: "text/plain",
            dataType: "text",
            success: callback
        });
    }
}

var x = new C();
$.when(x.load()).done(function(a1,a2) {
    console.log(x.text); //should print the content of file.txt
});
```

But this trew an exception `jQuery.Deferred exception: assignment to undeclared variable...`

Comment: Use an arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` doesn't refer to your instance in this line:

```
success: function(text) {
    this.myval = text;
}
```

You can make a temp variable referring to your instance in the outer method, like this:

```
load() {
    var that = this;
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "file.txt",
        // suppress "xml not well-formed error in firefox", 
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            if (xhr.overrideMimeType) { xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain"); }
        },
        contentType: "text/plain",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(text) {
            that.myval = text;
        }
    });
}
```

Or, you can use an arrow function:

```
load() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "file.txt",
        // suppress "xml not well-formed error in firefox", 
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            if (xhr.overrideMimeType) { xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain"); }
        },
        contentType: "text/plain",
        dataType: "text",
        success: (text) => {
            this.myval = text;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: They don't *have* to... there are more elegant solutions. Also, in the future if there's a duplicate (canonical) could you also vote to close as well instead of answering right away? This is an incredibly common problem.

Comment: Yeah, I rephrased that. Arrow function is the way to go.

Comment: @Li357 it is indeed extremely common. I had answered the exact same thing about an hour before this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929737. But it is hard to mark this as a duplicate of another question. I couldn't find any question that would fit.

Comment: Then don't keep answering. Vote to close as duplicates.

Comment: @Li357 think of noobs like me: I'm glad I got an answer. I have been searching for more than an hour before I posted this question.

Comment: @Markus Good to hear, and I'm not saying your question is bad. Dynamic this binding is really tricky and takes a lot getting used to. I'm just telling Phiter to, in the future, close as a duplicate (which is not an inherently bad thing) since the duplicate goes a lot more in depth.